# SQL Command where id is not the same from the foreign key (MariaDB)

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have three tables. Table1(id,name), Table2(id,name) and Table3(t1.id, t2.id)  I need a SELECT command that shows me everything from Table1 where id is not the same from the foreign key t1.id from Table3.

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for everything in Table1 that is not present in Table3's t1.id column.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT t1id
                 FROM Table3);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b1e79/1) in MySQL, but the syntax is valid for MariaDB too.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you're asking to see records from Table1 where a matching t1id does not exist in Table3?

Then:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Table3 AS t3 
    WHERE t3.t1id = t1.id
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table1.*
    FROM Table1
    LEFT JOIN Table3  ON Table1.id = Table3.t1id
    WHERE Table3.t1id IS NULL;
```